# Asp.Net Get Image from folder path according Login Name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to ask about asp.net
Best regards for everyone of you to answer and solve my question :)
The Case are when I'm Login, I want call the image Logo and put it in  according to username Login but I put the image on folder inside my web project. I named the image Logo according to every username that registered in my database.
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: How are you storing the "username" once they login? on session, or where?

Comment: i'm storing the username on session bro but i have change the rule that the image have to show according to the name's product. can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using webforms. You can add an asp:Image control in you webpage.

```
<%@ Page Title="MyPage" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForms.MyPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <!-- This is the element that will display your user image -->
    <asp:Image ID="LogoPicture" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Then inside the MyPage.aspx.cs file you can set the URL for the picture.

**C#**

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the username for current user however you will
        var username = User.Identity.Name;

        //Create the path for your logo picture
        string logoPath = string.Concat(ResolveUrl("~/Content/Logos/"), username, ".JPG");

        //Set the picture control image url accordingly
        LogoPicture.ImageUrl = logoPath;
    }
}
```

**VB**

```
Public Class MyPage
    Inherits Page

     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If (User IsNot Nothing AndAlso User.Identity IsNot Nothing) Then
        ' Get the username
        Dim username As String = User.Identity.Name

        ' Create path for the images for example this could be something like http://localhost/MyApp/Content/Logos/JohnCena.JPG
        Dim logoPath As String = String.Concat(ResolveUrl("~/Image"), username, ".JPG")

        ' Set the picture control image url accordingly
        LogoPicture.ImageUrl = logoPath
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Big thanks for your answer bro. but in this case i have changed the rule that the Logo showed according to the name's product. can you explain me the way? or i can implemented your above answer for my case now? i hope you can explain me by using vb language :)

Comment: I added the same code snippet in VB I can't really help with how to get product name or username because I don't know your application. So you might need to do something different then User.Identity.Name

Comment: You're very kind bro. Big thanks for your fast answer about my question. but i want explain you  a little about my application. i have database named MsUser and Product and the Folder Image i put inside the project. the case are, i want to show image Logo about the product after i logged in but the image logo according to the name of the product. so if the product name is 'A' I named the Logo as same as the product name too. my question is how i can call the image logo but according to the name product? Thanks before bro :)

Comment: Do you have the productName stored somewhere? I don't quite understand your problem. You can just replace the username variable with productName and set the path to "~/Image" and that should fix it.

Comment: Hi Tomi,
The rule is like this: i have folder in my web project named 'Image'. The image name I make it suitable with all the username (one example: if the username 'Joe' the image name on folder also i named with 'Joe' , that's why when username 'Joe' Login successfully the image show on web is Image with name 'Joe'. Can you explain me how to make like that using asp.net vb language? Big thanks for you sir :)

Comment: Thanks Tomi. I'll waiting for it :)

Comment: Hi Tomi,
When i using your code the image doesn't show but if i change the username become my real username example "Joe" the image showed. then i try to make MsgBox(username) to get the username and when i running the application the message box show with null result of the username. how to solve it sir? :)

Comment: What kind of authentication method are you using? And is your user authenticated?

Comment: i used a Login DAL authentication and all my user will be authenticated. How it works sir? :)

Comment: i use Forms Authentication tom.